# Removing orphaned inventory items

Tags: php, square-connect

I am working on an inventory check script using PHP's cURL to query the Square API. As expected, this returns multiple `InventoryEntry` objects as JSON.

However, this inventory list contains many items that have been removed from the store. (There are currently 644 entries in the Item Library, but 929 items appear in the JSON response.) As far as I can tell, there is no way to remove these items from the Inventory–the `Update Variation` endpoint requires an `item_id` which is no longer available for the deleted items, despite their variations persisting in the inventory database.

Does anyone know of a way to remove these orphaned inventory items via either the API or the Dashboard? (I called Square and asked if they could just `TRUNCATE` my item table but they don't have that kind of access on the support line.)

Alternatively, is it possible to either:

- Add the `item_id` to the `InventoryEntry` object or
- Allow the `Update Variation` endpoint to function without an `item_id` (i.e., just a `variation_id`)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for identifying this problematic bug in the Connect API. There is currently no way to filter out inventory information for deleted item variations. I've filed a bug report with the API engineering team.